# React: API call fails when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my code:

```
import Base from "./Base";
import axios from "axios";
import { createData } from "../../utils";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Today(props) {
  const [scoops, setScoops] = useState(0);

  //Fetch api/scoops/today
  const fetchScoops = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/scoops/today/");
    setScoops(res.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchScoops();
  }, []);

  console.log(scoops[0]);

  const rows = [
    createData(0, 1, scoops[0].title, "http://example.com"),
    createData(1, 2, "Paul McCartney", "http://example.com"),
    createData(2, 3, "Tom Scholz", "http://example.com"),
    createData(3, 4, "Michael Jackson", "http://example.com"),
    createData(4, 5, "Bruce Springsteen", "http://example.com"),
  ];

  return <Base rows={rows} duration="Today" />;
}
```

Here is what the console returns:

```
> undefined
> Today.js:20 {url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/scoops/1/', title: 'Hello World!', rank: 0, created_at: '2021-10-05T04:44:52.027336Z', updated_at: '2021-10-05T04:44:52.027336Z'}
```

The problem is when I refresh the page, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

Help would be much appreciated!

**Update**:
[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) solved the issue, this works great.

```
scoops[0]?.title
```

Comment: When you refresh the page, the `scoop` (local stage) will be set as 0. That is the problem. Try to initialize array like this `const [scoops, setScoops] = useState([]);`

Comment: Tried to initialize it that way but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are initializing `scoops` as `0` but using it like an array: `scoops[0]`

Try initializing `scoops` as an empty array. So something like this should work:

```
const [scoops, setScoops] = useState([]);
```

Also, where you are doing this: `scoops[0].title` you should instead use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and use `scoops[0]?.title`

Comment: Tried that but no luck!

Comment: On your line where you do this: `scoops[0].title` try this instead: `scoops[0]?.title`

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @HassanNaqvi Optional Chaining solves my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the initial `scoops` state to `[]`

```
const [scoops, setScoops] = useState([]);
```

render `scoops` when data fetched using `conditionalRendering`

```
return <> {scoops.lenght > 0 && <Base rows={rows} duration="Today" />} </>;
```

Comment: I tried both the suggestion, unfortunately they do not seem to work for me. I really loved the conditionalRendering idea but due to the undefined value returned at the refresh, it never shows my table when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
scoops?.[0]
```